# How to open a .msg file?

Tags: excel, vba, msg

I want to open a .msg file.

I can't open .msg files as I would workbooks.

```vb
Sub OpenMail()
    
    Workbooks("MyBook").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Dim MyItem1 As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MyItem2 As Outlook.MailItem

    If Range("A1").Value > 0 Then 
        Set MyItem1.Open = "C:\Users\jeff\OneDrive\Documents\Email #1.msg"
        MyItem1.Display

    Else If Range("A1").Value < 0 Then
        Set MyItem2.Open = "C:\Users\jeff\OneDrive\Documents\Email #2.msg"
        MyItem2.Display
    Else 
        MsgBox("No items to open")

    End If

End Sub
```

It gives me

> Run-time error 91
> Object variable or With block variable not set

I connected Outlook in Reference Library (under Tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the Outlook object itself first and then use it to open the message.

You "Set" the Mailitem to then be the newly opened message:

```
Public Sub foo()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim MyItem1 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MyItem2 As Outlook.MailItem

Workbooks("MyBook").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

If Range("A1").Value > 0 Then

      Set MyItem1 = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\Users\jeff\OneDrive\Documents\Email #1.msg")

      MyItem1.Display

ElseIf Range("A1").Value < 0 Then
      Set MyItem2 = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\Users\jeff\OneDrive\Documents\Email #2.msg")
        MyItem2.Display
Else
      MsgBox ("No items to open")

End If

set objOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also just as a note there isn't a space in the ElseIf statement (that may have just been a copy and paste issue though).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Earl_of_Duke! Your code works! And the code executes faster while Outlook is open than while it is closed

Comment: No problem, I just realised I neglected to set the obj to nothing at the end so have updated.

Answer (score -1):

Try dimming as object instead.  Also, you may need to set your Outlook session to either reference Outlook if already open, or open Outlook if it is not open already.

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oItem1 As Object
Dim oItem2 As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'oApp.Session.Logon -> if needed, uncomment

Set oItem1 = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\test1.msg")
Set oItem2 = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\test2.msg")

'Condition
'if true
oItem1.Display 
'else
oItem2.Display
'end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jenn for your response!